# Android Studio sql database display in listview and can multiple select with it

Tags: android, multiple-select

i want to display the contact in mg SQL database in listview and i can select multiple contact and copy the email address of it in next activity..

here is the code that display the contact in my sql database but i wont allow me to multiple select them..

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private ListView contact_list=null;
    private EditText search=null;

    private List contacts=null;
    private Contact contact=null;
    private Service service=null;

    public static final int OPTION_DIALOG = 1;

    private PopupWindow popupWindow;
    private ListView menuListView;
    EditText editTextEmail, editTextSubject, editTextMessage;

    Button btnSend, btnAttachment;

    String email, subject, message, attachmentFile;

    Uri URI = null;

    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 101;

    int columnIndex;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        this.contact_list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        databaseAccess.open();
        List<String> contact = databaseAccess.getQuotes();
        databaseAccess.close();

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,     
        android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, contact);
        this.contact_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        service = new Service(this);
        init();
        getContent();


        initPopupWindow();
    }



    private void init(){
        contact_list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contact_list);
        contact_list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        contact_list.setOnItemClickListener(new ViewItemListener());
       search = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
       search.addTextChangedListener(new SearchTextChangedListener());
    }



    private void getContent() {
        List mylist = new ArrayList();
        String queryName = search.getText().toString();
        contacts = service.getByName(queryName); // get an contacts array
        if (contacts != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < contacts.size(); i++) {
                Contact contact = (Contact) contacts.get(i);
                // HashMap
                HashMap map = new HashMap();
                if (contact.getDepartment().equals("IT"))
                {
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_mis);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("HRD")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_hrd);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("Pubs")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_pubs);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("Finance")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_finance);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("Sales")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_sales);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("CRC")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_crc);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("OED")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_oed);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("OP")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_op);

                  } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("EMD")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_emd);

                } if (contact.getDepartment().equals("TD")){
                    map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_td);

                    //}else {
                 //   map.put("tv_image", R.drawable.icon_spred);
                }
                map.put("tv_name", contact.getName());
                map.put("tv_phone", contact.getPhone());
                mylist.add(map);
            }
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, mylist, 
        R.layout.my_list_item,
                    new String[]{"tv_image", "tv_name", "tv_phone"},
                    new int[]{R.id.user_image, R.id.item_name, 
        R.id.item_phone});
            contact_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.add_contact) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
        if(id == R.id.more) {
            if(popupWindow.isShowing())
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            else
                popUp();
            return true;
        }
    if(id == R.id.emailaddress) {
        if(popupWindow.isShowing())
            popupWindow.dismiss();
        else
            popUp();
        return true;
    }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onRestart() {
        getContent();
        super.onRestart();
    }


    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        Dialog dialog;
        switch(id){
            case OPTION_DIALOG:
                dialog = createOptionDialog();
                break;
            default:
                dialog = null;
        }
        return dialog;
    }

    private Dialog createOptionDialog(){
        final Dialog optionDialog;
        View optionDialogView = null;
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        optionDialogView = li.inflate(R.layout.option_dialog, null);

        optionDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setView(optionDialogView).create();
        ImageButton ibCall = 
        (ImageButton)optionDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_call);
        ImageButton ibView = `enter code 
        here`(ImageButton)optionDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_view);
        ImageButton ibSms = 
        (ImageButton)optionDialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialog_sms);
        ImageButton ibEmailadd = (ImageButton) 
            optionDialogView.findViewById((R.id.dialog_emailadd));

        ibCall.setOnClickListener(new ImageButtonListener());

        ibSms.setOnClickListener(new ImageButtonListener());
        ibEmailadd.setOnClickListener(new ImageButtonListener());
        return optionDialog;
    }



    private void initPopupWindow(){
        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null);
        menuListView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.popup_list_view);
        popupWindow = new PopupWindow(view, 260, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRA`enter code here`P_CONTENT);

        List<Map<String, Object>> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("menu_about", "About CFA");
        data.add(map);

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, data, R.layout.popup_list_item,
                new String[]{"menu_about"}, new int[]{R.id.menu_about});
        menuListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        menuListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                switch (position) {

                    case 0:
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        popupWindow.dismiss();
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
        popupWindow.setTouchable(true);
        popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
    }



    private void popUp(){

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(this.findViewById(R.id.more), 0, 2);
    }



    //**************** internal class as Listener ******************
    class SearchTextChangedListener implements TextWatcher{

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            getContent();
        }

    }
    class ViewItemListener implements OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            // get the contact from the contacts array.
            contact = (Contact)contacts.get(position);
            showDialog(OPTION_DIALOG);

        }
    }
    class ImageButtonListener implements OnClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.dialog_call:
                    if (contact.getPhone().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Phone No.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + contact.getPhone()));
                        intent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    dismissDialog(OPTION_DIALOG);
                    break;

                case R.id.dialog_view:
                    // Send an intent, Active the detailActivity
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DetailActivity.class);

                    intent.putExtra("id", contact.getId());
                    startActivity(intent);
                    dismissDialog(OPTION_DIALOG);
                    break;

                case R.id.dialog_emailadd:

                    if (contact.getEmail().equals("")) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Email Add.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else{
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmailActivity.class);
                intent3.putExtra("id", contact.getId());
                startActivity(intent3);
            }
        dismissDialog(OPTION_DIALOG);
        break;

                case R.id.dialog_sms:
                    if (contact.getPhone().equals("")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Phone no.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                        intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
                        intent1.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + contact.getPhone()));
                        intent1.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
                        startActivity(intent1);
                    }

                    dismissDialog(OPTION_DIALOG);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add a check box to the view, if ticked then on a **go* button/event, process all that are ticked?

Comment: how can i do that? you mean in the layout?

Comment: Ok you're using simpleadadapter. However, I think if you add a boolean  the to array, then the simple adapter may add a check box. Personally I always use cutsom adapters where you define the view (via an xml layout).

Comment: do you have any sample of that? im sorry i wasnt that knowledgeable in this project..

Comment: bear with me. I will check if I have something that isn't too complicated.

Comment: Please invest some effort in punctuation and capitalisation. Try to provide a [MCVE] to illustrate your point.

Comment: thank you very much... i just want the listview that display sql db and then i can select multiple email add and then copy them in textbox. just like when you add many email add in just one email. also the attachement that can be choose in the mobile files ... thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Ok here's a very basic `ListView` with a **custom adapter** that adds a `checkbox` for each data item.

I've made it so that alternate `checkboxes` are checked, to give a basic idea of how you can manipulate stuff in the adpater which you can't do, at least easily, in simple adapters.

There are 4 components The Class for the activity, a layout (the XML) for the main activity, including the Listview, a second layout (XML) for each entry in the Listview (each row) and lastly the custom adapter.

**MainActivity**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView mylistview;
    private ArrayList<String> mylist = new ArrayList<>();
    private MyListViewCustomAdapter myListViewCustomAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mylist.add("Fred");
        mylist.add("Bert");
        mylist.add("Harry");

        mylistview = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.mylistview);
        myListViewCustomAdapter = new MyListViewCustomAdapter(this,R.layout.activity_main,mylist);
        mylistview.setAdapter(myListViewCustomAdapter);

    }
}
```

**activity_main** The Layout with the ListView

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="mjt.listviewwithcutsomadapter.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/mylistview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**mylistview_entry** the layout for each entry(row) of the `ListView`.
Note the `CheckBox`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mylistviewentry_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/mylistviewentry_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And finally the Custom Adapter **MyListViewCustomAdapter**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MyListViewCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private Context context;
    private ArrayList<String> mylist;
    private TextView tv_name;
    private CheckBox tv_chkbox;

    public MyListViewCustomAdapter(Activity context, int layout, ArrayList<String> mylist) {
        super(context, layout, mylist);
        this.context = context;
        this.mylist = mylist;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        if(view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.mylistview_entry,parent,false);
        }

        tv_name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistviewentry_name);
        tv_chkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.mylistviewentry_checkbox);

        tv_name.setText(mylist.get(position));
        if(position % 2 == 0) {
            tv_chkbox.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            tv_chkbox.setChecked(false);
        }
        return  view;
    }
}
```

The Custom adapter basically combines the data with the entry/row layout each time a row is processed, for `ListView`'s this is done in the `getView` method.

Comment: thank you very much for your time to answer @mikeT i will try this. :)